# auto increment max date of GMDatePicker in C#.net

Tags: asp.net

`DateTime s = GMDStartDate.Date;
 GMDStartDate.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
 GMDStartDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;`

I want to auto increment the max date of GMDatePicker by 2 months from the current date in C#.net..?Please can anyone tell this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AddMonths()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) Like this :

```
GMDStartDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
```

Comment: Ohh..Thank You very much Sai...It worked properly & was very helpful..Thank You...